# How do you convert hdf5 files into a format that is readable by SAS Enterprise Miner(sas7bdat)

Tags: sas, hdf5, enterprise-miner

I have a subset of the data set called as 'million song dataset' available on the website (http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/millionsong/)  on which I would like to perform data mining operations on SAS Enterprise Miner (13.2).

The subset I have downloaded contains 10,000 files and they are all in HDF5 format. 
How do you convert hdf5 files into a format that is readable by SAS Enterprise Miner(sas7bdat)

Answer (score 1):

On Windows there is an ODBC driver for HD5.  If you have SAS/ACCESS ODBC then you can use that to read the file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's feasible to do this directly, as hdf5 seems to be a binary file format. You might be able to use another application to convert hdf5 to a plain text format and then write SAS code to import that.

I think some of the other files on this page might be easier to import:
http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/millionsong/pages/getting-dataset